# Error in the void print function

Tags: c++, dynamic, allocation

What I am trying to do is print out the elements that is dynamically allocated.

Here is my issue, I'm new in learning, and not understanding why this below cannot work? If you could please give a brief description why this is producing the error, I'm just trying to learn from my mistakes. I know I could just dynamically allocate the user input in the main function, but I wanted to see by trial and error if I could I just create an input function where I call it in my print function to produce the  user elements after it is dynamically allocated.

Any suggestion on what I could do to make this work would be awesome, thanks.

```
void print(int* input, int size)
{
    uinput(input,size);
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++)
    {
        std::cout << " " << input[i];// Error -> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x0)
    }
}
```

The entire code without the print function above

```
#include <iostream>
void print(int*, int);
void uinput(int*, int);
int* copy(const int*, int);
int main()
{
    int size;
    int* input;
    std::cout << "Enter the size of the array";
    std::cin >> size;


    std::cout << "Original array:" << std::endl;


    print(input,size);
    int* expander = copy(input,size);

    std::cout << "New array:" << std::endl;

    print(expander,size);

    delete [] input;
    delete [] expander;
    input= nullptr;
    expander = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
void uinput(int* input, int size)
{
    int* uInput = new int[size];
    for(int k=0; k <size;k++)
    {
        std::cin >> uInput[k];
    }
}
int* copy(const int* input, int size)
{
    int* newArray = new int[size*2];
    int j =0;
    for(int i = 0; i <size*2;i++)
    {
        if(j >i)
        {
            newArray[j]=newArray[i];
            j++;
        }
        else
            newArray[j]=0;
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Update: I tried to modified where I just let it point to the size of uInput function, but that didn't work.

```
void uinput(int size)
{
    int* uInput = new int[size];
    for(int k=0; k <size;k++)
    {
        std::cin >> uInput[k];
    }
}
```

Comment: `input` within uinput() is a copy of your pointer. Better use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure how std::vectors work, I haven't learn vectors yet. I was hoping maybe after I figure out how I can fix this, I would try using it with vectors.

Comment: Well that's the point: you shoud NOT use `new`/`new[]`. Always smart pointers and `std::vector`. It's pretty simple here: `std::vector<int> input(size);` Then passing it by reference.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that instead, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `uinput` function allocates memory, but does not make use of the `input` parameter that you send it.  As a result, trying to iterate over items supposedly pointed to by that pointer, which has not been initialized to point at anything, is undefined behavior, causing your program to crash, in this case.

Comment: Even if it did use the input parameter it would not work because the `int*` is being passed by value.

Comment: @ Elkvis, I thought I had my input parameter pointing to the int of size? That way I could pass the size of the array the user is trying to dynamically allocate. To enter the elements for the array. I know I am wrong, but this was my thinking process when I wrote it.

Comment: In `uinput()`, you allocate storage, but that storage is lost as soon as the function returns.  You don't ever do anything with it after reading in the values.  One option might be to have `uinput()` return the pointer, in which case `print()` does not need to accept one as a parameter.